# OCCI - setDataBuffer + vector<struct>

Tags: c++, oracle, occi

Trying to minimize amount of lines for an OCCI array fetch by storing a struct containing a char buffer into a vector, code below:

```
    struct Columns { char buffer[1000][300]; };

    int i = 1;
    Columns col;
    ub4* ub = NULL;
    results->setDataBuffer( i++, col.buffer, OCCI_SQLT_STR, sizeof( col.buffer[ 0 ] ), ub );
        vec.push_back( col );

    cout << "Before, vec size: " << vec.size( ) << "\n"; // prints 1, as expected
    while ( results->next( 1000 ) ) {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < results->getNumArrayRows( ); ++j ) {
            cout << vec[ 0 ].buffer[ j ] << endl;
        }
```

Now for some reason, this doesnt work. However, if instead of using col.buffer, I create a char buffer[1000][300] and toss that into setDataBuffer then in the cout part do:
    cout << buffer[j] << endl;

that works just fine. So I'm not really sure where I'm screwing up?

the char buffer is the exact same thing as col.buffer, is it not?

I don't think it matters but struct Columns is defined in the header file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the `setDataBuffer` fills the buffer you pass as parameter (which is col.buffer here), then you push it into the vector, so a new `struct Columns` is allocated by `vec` and it copy `col` content. Now `col` and `vec[0]` are two different objects.

Then you call some methods which fills the buffer you first passed to it. So it fills `col.buffer`, and you read `vec[0].buffer`, which are different because they are 2 different objects.

One solution would instead be to do `vec.emplace_back();` to create one instance, and then pass `vec[0].buffer` to `setDataBuffer`. But be careful with addresses of elements in vectors. If you modify the vector (adding or removing elements) it can reallocate it's content, and the element addresses might change.

Comment: So push_back doesn't copy the content of the char buffer? That's confusing, the documentation on it says it copies, figured it would copy everything. The emplace_back solution worked however, thank you.

Comment: Well it copy it, but once it's copied it's another object, only with an identical content. Maybe you used to dev in a different language such as C# of JS which use object as reference by default. This mean that if you do a copy of an object `a` named `b` and modify `b`, the content of `a` is also modified. If you want a real copy, you need to clone it. In C/C++ it's different, it uses values by default. This mean if you do `a = b`, `a` is a clone of `b`, if you modify one of them, the other one is not modified (unless you explicitly​ defined `a` as a reference, like `int &a = b;`)

Comment: So what happens exactly? The original goes out of scope/replaced then poof, data's gone? Using a vector doesn't seem to work with the setdatabuffer function, however. I don't quite understand why, would you happen to know? It works with 1 column but if there are more than 1 columns it crashes.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure of why it crashes with more than 1 column, but once you pushed back `col` into the vec, `col` and `vec` are two distinct objects. They both exist. But since you passed the `col.buffer`, and copied `col` content into `vec[0]` before updating the buffer's content (which I guess is what `results->next` do, only `col.buffer` is modified, so `vec[0]` doesn't change at all. I hope I helped, tell me if you have more questions